# How to calculate hydrogenic radial wave functions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, physical-chemistry, software, special-functions

I'm learning *Atkins' Physical Chemistry*, and in chapter 9 I found that I cannot get the hydrogenic radial wave function from the formula the book given.

$$
R_{n,l}(r)=N_{n,l} \rho^l L^{2l+1}_{n+1}(\rho) e^{-\rho/2}
$$
where $\rho=\frac{2Zr}{na}$

However, I can't get the same results that the book given.
[image: one page from the book]

Take $n=1$ and $l=0$ as an example, use Wolfram Mathematica code:

`Module[{n = 1, l = 0}, 
 Integrate[((2 Z r/(n a))^l LaguerreL[n + 1, 2 l + 1, 
      2 Z r/(n a)] Exp[-Z r/(n a)])^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}]]`

This code give $\frac{3a}{2Z}$, so the normalization constant should be $\sqrt{\frac{2Z}{3a}}$. Then,

`Module[{n = 1, 
  l = 0}, (2 Z r/(n a))^l LaguerreL[n + 1, 2 l + 1, 
   2 Z r/(n a)] Exp[-Z r/(n a)]/Sqrt[3 a/(2 Z)]]`

using $\rho=\frac{2Zr}{na}$,I get
$$
R_{1,0} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}(\frac{Z}{a})^{1/2} (3-3 \rho + \frac{\rho^2}{2})e^{-\rho/2}
$$

It's different from the equation in the table.

I am using Wolfram Mathematica 11 as the math software to deal with the algebra stuff. So, I think there is no mistakes with math.

I really have no idea where is wrong.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. If you substitute the Laguerre polynomials back into the Schrodinger equation you should be able to see that they satisfy it, though it's a somewhat fiddly calculation.

Comment: Your result is wrong. $R_{10}$ shouldn't have any radial nodes. There is likely an error in your implementation but you'd have to post your code to be able to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I know what's happening.
The book (the 9th edition) is wrong.

The radial wave function should be
$$
R_{n,l}(r)=N_{n,l}\rho^lL_{n-l-1}^{2l+1}(\rho)e^{-\rho/2}
$$

Notice the Laguerre polynomials, the true is $L_{n-l-1}^{2l+1}(\rho)$ , not $L_{n+1}^{2l+1}(\rho)$ .

This mistake is fixed in the new book (the 10th edition).